# os.rename — если папки нет, возникает ошибка. Как это предотвратить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ос

Есть следующий код:

```py
os.rename("D:\Music", "I'm")
```

Но если на диске нет указанной папки, возникает ошибка и программа останавливается.

Как сделать так, чтобы, при отсутствии папки, эта инструкция пропускалась и программа продолжалась?

---

И ещё проблема с созданием папок:

```py
os.mkdir("you")
path = r'D:\Games'
```

Когда указываю другой путь (как на примере), папка создаётся в директории с `Python`.

Что с этим делать?

Comment: вам дали уже несколько ответов - может стоить выбрать какой то из них правильным, чтобы люди, столкнувшиеся с той же проблемой знали, на на ответ есть правильное решение??

Answer (score 8):

```py
try:
    os.rename("D:\Music", "I'm")

except OSError:
    pass
```

B `os` я не силен, но мне кажется, что директорию надо сменить

```
os.chdir()
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете проверить факт существования директории с помощью `os.path.exists`.

***Пример:***

```py
if os.path.exists('D:/Music'):
    os.rename('D:/Music', "I'm")
```

---

Насчёт создания папки, она создаётся в текущем каталоге (то есть в каталоге, из которого запускается программа).

Вы можете изменить текущий каталог с помощью `os.chdir`.

Comment: Это не избавит от проблем, если переименовать не удастся по другим причинам, как то защита от записи в каталог назначение или источника... а на win ещё и если файл открыт кем-нибудь...

Comment: @Fat-Zer В первой редакции вопрос был следующий: _"Как сделать так, что если нету папки, эту функцию игнорирует и код продолжается?"_. Код удовлетворяет условию. А если возникает иная проблема, то ошибка как раз и должна возникать.

Comment: Конечно, можно обернуть всё в `try`, но это ужасная практика, которая приводит к фантомным багам и, как следствие, ещё большему количеству проблем.

Comment: как раз способ с `try` — правильный... разве что на практике контроль ошибок стоит несколько расширить... на самом деле особая порочность в варианте с предварительной проверкой не в том, что не все ошибки контролируются, а в том, что каталог может быть удалён другой программой после проверки, но до переименования...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Действительно, об этом я как-то не подумал, Вы правы.

Comment: и по поводу того что есть другие ошибки, я не хотел придираться... просто об этом стоило упомянуть...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Я всегда рад обоснованной критике :) Спасибо, что упомянули.

Comment: Но ответ править/удалять уже не буду, вдруг кто-то откроет для себя новую функцию. А способ с `try` описан в ответе выше.